# Where could I find a primer on database sharding?

Tags: sharding

I have a database that is currently sharded.  This is the first time that I have come across a sharded database and would like to know a bit more about them.

Things like:

- When is it a good idea to shard a database?
- At what database size is it a good idea to shard a database?
- How easy it is to remove sharding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [article](http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/)